# More granular visualizations in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies if this is a basic question, but I can't seem to find any examples of what I want to do online: I think it may be an issue of ggplot's "tidy" conception of data.

Anyway, say I'm working with the mtcars dataset and want to visualize the average mpg for one make of car, e.g. Honda, vs the average for all the cars. Ggplot makes it very easy visualizing *all* categories on a certain variable, i.e. the mgps of all makes, but doesn't seem to allow for the isolation of certain points of interest. Is this true? If not, how would I do this?

I have been running through tutorials on visualization in R, but have not been able to find examples of people breaking down the data in this way.

As such, I don't really have a constructive code to share.

Comment: As you mention yourself, the question is a bit broad. Is there any plot that you are able to create to use as an example? Maybe you can use e.g. photoshop to make an example of your desired output. I'm sure there are a lot of people who can help you with this kind of issue, but it's difficult without having a real question to answer.

Comment: "how would I do this?" Calculate the averages outside ggplot2 and pass the result as a tidy data.frame to `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it with other tidyverse functions.

1) Save a version of mtcars with rownames in a column, and split that column into Make and Model.

2) Get the Honda avg with `dplyr::filter()` and `dplyr::summarize()`. Use `dplyr::bind_rows` to combine with the total average to get a tibble with the data you want to show.

3) (optional) Use `forcats::fct_relevel` to reorder to put Total last. For instance, if you had picked "Volvo", it would naturally show up last alphabetically, instead of first like Honda.

4) Plot!

```
library(tidyverse)
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  separate(rowname, c("Make", "Model"), extra = "merge")


my_mtcars %>%
  # Avg for Honda
  group_by(Make) %>%
  summarize(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  filter(Make == "Honda") %>%

  # Combine with total avg, and make "Total" show up last, regardless of alphabetical order
  bind_rows(my_mtcars %>% summarize(mpg = mean(mpg), Make = "Total")) %>%
  mutate(Make = fct_relevel(Make, "Total", after = Inf)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(Make, mpg, label = round(mpg, 1))) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = 1.5, fontface = "bold", color = "white")
```

[image]